# Angular+2 adding values to array of objects and iterate

Tags: angular, data-structures

I have a Proposal [id, name, date] and a ProposalVote [id, user, votes] objects. When I get my array of Proposals filled, I want to show each Proposal record with the total votes it has. I call my service and I get the ProposalVote, but now I have to show them in my component.html together...

Which data structure is the best to do it?

```
Proposal: 1     TotalProposalVotes: 123
Proposal: 2     TotalProposalVote: 456
```

Consider that the next thing I need is to add the totalUSERProposalVotes (and other things my be added next)

```
Proposal: 1     TotalProposalVotes: 123     totalUSERProposalVotes: 3
Proposal: 2     TotalProposalVote: 456      totalUSERProposalVotes: 4
```

I imagine that I can change the proposal model but that looks like a messy option. 
A HashMap sounds fine for the first case, but not for the second.

PROPOSALS

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';
import { IVoteProposal } from 'app/shared/model/vote-proposal.model';

export const enum ProposalType {
  STUDY = 'STUDY',
  APPROVED = 'APPROVED',
  DEVELOPMENT = 'DEVELOPMENT',
  PRODUCTION = 'PRODUCTION'
}

export const enum ProposalRole {
  USER = 'USER',
  ORGANIZER = 'ORGANIZER',
  MANAGER = 'MANAGER',
  ADMIN = 'ADMIN'
}

export interface IProposal {
  id?: number;
  creationDate?: Moment;
  proposalName?: string;
  proposalType?: ProposalType;
  proposalRole?: ProposalRole;
  releaseDate?: Moment;
  isOpen?: boolean;
  isAccepted?: boolean;
  isPaid?: boolean;
  voteProposals?: IVoteProposal[];
  proposalUserId?: number;
  postId?: number;
}

export class Proposal implements IProposal {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public creationDate?: Moment,
    public proposalName?: string,
    public proposalType?: ProposalType,
    public proposalRole?: ProposalRole,
    public releaseDate?: Moment,
    public isOpen?: boolean,
    public isAccepted?: boolean,
    public isPaid?: boolean,
    public voteProposals?: IVoteProposal[],
    public proposalUserId?: number,
    public postId?: number
  ) {
    this.isOpen = this.isOpen || false;
    this.isAccepted = this.isAccepted || false;
    this.isPaid = this.isPaid || false;
  }
}
```

And VOTES:

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';

export interface IVoteProposal {
  id?: number;
  creationDate?: Moment;
  votePoints?: number;
  proposalId?: number;
  proposalUserId?: number;
}

export class VoteProposal implements IVoteProposal {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public creationDate?: Moment,
    public votePoints?: number,
    public proposalId?: number,
    public proposalUserId?: number
  ) {}
}
```

Thanks for your help. Please, explain your solution as much as possible.

Comment: If you already have an array of all the data, the best thing imo would be to use `array.reduce()` to create the data structure you need. Would work well for both expected results showed here.

Comment: Could you provide a JSON sample of each object ? So that I could work on a concrecte example of it.

Comment: Thank Alex. There it goes.